# open GL ES1.0 Trails

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am new to open GL, I just want to move a circle randomly in the screen , when the user touches the circle , I need to know the hit and miss.
this is what I'm able to achieve through the online classes.

```
render class:


    public class HelloOpenGLES10Renderer implements Renderer {
    private int points = 250;
    private float vertices[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    private FloatBuffer vertBuff;
    public float x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f;
    public boolean color = false;
    boolean first = true;

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
        gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0f);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        Log.i("TAG", "change" + width + ":" + height);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        float ratio = (float) width / height;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0f, 0f, -5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

        Log.i("TAG", "CREATE");
        gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        initShapes();

    }

    private void initShapes() {

        vertices = new float[(points + 1) * 3];
        for (int i = 3; i < (points + 1) * 3; i += 3) {
            double rad = (i * 360 / points * 3) * (3.14 / 180);
            vertices[i] = (float) Math.cos(rad) * 0.10f;
            vertices[i + 1] = (float) Math.sin(rad) * 0.10f;
            vertices[i + 2] = 0;
        }
        ByteBuffer bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertBuff = bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
        vertBuff.put(vertices);
        vertBuff.position(0);

    }

}

Activity:
    package com.example.opengltrail;

    import java.util.Random;

    import android.app.Activity;
   import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.FloatMath;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;
    float oldx = 0, oldy = 0;
    private HelloOpenGLES10Renderer m;
    ProgressDialogThread p;
    ProgressDialogThread123 t;
    boolean stop = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGLView = new GLSurfaceView(this);

        m = new HelloOpenGLES10Renderer();

        mGLView.setRenderer(m);
        mGLView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        setContentView(mGLView);

        mGLView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        p = new ProgressDialogThread();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGLView.onPause();
        p.stop();
        stop = false;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGLView.onResume();
        t = new ProgressDialogThread123();

        t.start();
        p.start();

    }

    /**
     * gets u the random number btw 0.0 to 1.0
     */
    public float getmearandom() {
        Random rng = new Random();
        float next = rng.nextFloat();
        Integer i = rng.nextInt();
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            next = next * (-1);
        return next;
    }

    class ProgressDialogThread123 extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();

            for (; stop;) {
                p.run();
            }

        }
    }

    class ProgressDialogThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            if (stop) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                m.x = getmearandom();
                m.y = getmearandom();
                Log.i("m.x=" + m.x + ":", "m.y=" + m.y);
                mGLView.requestRender();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        float x1 = ((x * 2) / 480);
        float y1 = ((y * 2) / 724);
        x1 = -1 + x1;
        y1 = -1 + y1;
        if (y < 362) {
            if (y1 > 0)
                y1 = -y1;
        } else if (y > 362) {
            if (y1 < 0)
                y1 = -y1;
        } else {
            y1 = 0;
        }

        if (x > 240) {
            if (x1 < 0)
                x1 = -x1;

        } else if (x < 240) {
            if (x1 > 0)
                x1 = -x1;
        } else {
            x1 = 0;
        }

        Log.i("x1=" + x1, "y1=" + y1);
        float d = (((m.x - x1) * (m.x - x1)) + ((m.y - y1) * (m.y - y1)));

        float dd = FloatMath.sqrt(d);
        if (dd <= 0.10f) {
            m.color = true;
            // mGLView.requestRender();
            Log.i("Tag", "Circle");
        }
        // m.x += 0.10f;

        return true;
    }
}

Please anyone help me !! thanks in advance
```

Comment: Forgive me for asking an irrelevant question but what seems to be the problem?

Comment: i just want to know when the user clicks on the screen , whthr it is circle or not!! m am unable to do that.

Comment: one more this is that the View is not covering the full height of the screen .. i e when i print the value of the screen it is coming as 724 instead of 800.(normal 800X480)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only drawing in 2d I suggest you loose "frustum" and "lookAt" and replace them with "ortho" with coordinates: `ortho(viewOrigin.x, viewOrigin.x + viewSize.width, viewOrigin.y + viewSize.height, viewOrigin.y, -1.0f, 1.0f)`. This will make your GL coordinate system same as your view coordinates. As for circle vertices rather create them with radius of 1.0f. Now to draw the circle, before the draw call you just have to "push" matrix, translate to screen coordinates (X, Y, .0f), scale to radius R in pixels (R, R, 1.0f) and "pop" the matrix after the call.. Now to check on touch if the circle was hit:

```
`bool didHit = ((touch.x-cicrcleCenter.x)*(touch.x-cicrcleCenter.x) +   
               (touch.y-cicrcleCenter.y)*(touch.y-cicrcleCenter.y))  
               <  R*R`;
```

Note that "viewOrigin" in "ortho" depends on where you are catching touches: If you are catching them in the same view it will probably be at (0,0) no matter where the view is. Those coordinates should correspond to coordinates you receive in your touch event when pressing at upper left and bottom right corners of your view.

If you really need to draw in 3d and you will have to use frustum, you will need to get inverse of your projection matrix to create 3d rays from your touches and then check for hits the same way you would for bullets if you like.